# Error on vagrant up: Memory could not be written

Tags: vagrant

I receive the following error when trying to execute the command "vagrant up":

```
---------------------------
VBoxHeadless.exe - Application Error
---------------------------
The instruction at 0x00007FFDEFEACD38 referenced memory at 0x0000000000003CB0. The memory could not be read.


Click on OK to terminate the program
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Here is the console output log:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'absolute-mysql' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'absolute' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> absolute-mysql: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> absolute-mysql: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is available! You currently
==> absolute-mysql: have version '20171019.0.0'. The latest is version '20171205.0.1'. Run
==> absolute-mysql: `vagrant box update` to update.
==> absolute-mysql: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> absolute-mysql: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> absolute-mysql: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    absolute-mysql: Adapter 1: nat
    absolute-mysql: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> absolute-mysql: Forwarding ports...
    absolute-mysql: 3306 (guest) => 3306 (host) (adapter 1)
    absolute-mysql: 22 (guest) => 8022 (host) (adapter 1)
    absolute-mysql: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> absolute-mysql: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> absolute-mysql: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "de3601aa-69df-49cb-abdf-698a1bbb91c7", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The VM session was aborted
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface ISession
```

Please let me know if there is any further information I should provide. I am running the 64 bit version of vagrant and virtual box on Windows 10.

Comment: does it happen only for `absolute-mysql` box or all boxes which you try to run? also please paste your `Vagrantfile`. Give it a try and run `cmd.exe` with administrative privileges and then run `vagrant up`

Comment: I tried running as admin, and did not make a difference. I have also tried creating a test vagrant box and every time I have executed the "vagrant up" command, I've been hit with a bluescreen. My vagrantfile for the absolute box can be viewed here:

https://pastebin.com/raw/AWr2bV9D

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the box is simply broken or incompatible with your hardware.

Comment: have you tried upgrading VirtualBox? Or uninstalling and reinstalling? Also, is your BIOS set to enable virtualisation?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, and hopefully there will be a bug-fix for it soon.

In the meantime, I have managed to start the install process by attaching the .iso image in the VirtualBox IDE Storage Settings page rather than the "mount" dialog that causes the error.

Open the settings for your VM in the VirtualBox UI, go to Storage, click on the "empty" entry in the list of IDE Controllers, and select the disk icon over to the right of the screen. Finally, select to "Choose Virtual Optical Disk File", and select your .iso of choice. Then start the VM and it should boot just fine.